# How to run a bash script with psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, bash, psql

Sorry for the extremely noob questions but I'm completely new to shell scripting.

Simply put, I need to connect to a PostgreSQL database hosted on AWS, obtain some data, save it as a CSV and turn this process into an executable bash script. I have succeeded in doing this on pgAdmin but am unable to do so from my terminal.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
#!/bin/bash

psql 
-U username
-h hostname
-d database
-p password 

copy 
(SELECT data FROM table LIMIT 100;) to "Users/name/Downloads" With CSV
```

Now I can't seem to complete the process of connecting to the database within the bash script, and there may also be a problem with the SQL Query as it acts differently with psql than on pgAdmin.

According to what I could find it may be useful to use su or sudo commands, some people are doing --U instead of -U but nothing i've tried seems to work thus far.

For reference, I am using PostgreSQL version 12. I'm new to the game and could use a little help, where am I going wrong here?

Comment: from which user you are trying to run this script? first try to run this command from your command prompt. if it is working on command prompt then only put it in script file

Comment: The user I'm trying to run from is reporting. I have read only access

Comment: @AliImran : What you posted, is not bash code. You don't expect bash to understand `-U` , do you? So you want to run SQL commands from bash, via PostreSQL?

Comment: @AliImran : [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is what you can do with psql from a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\copy` in a "here document":

```sh
#!/bin/bash

psql -U username -h hostname -d database -p password -f - <<EOF
\copy (SELECT data FROM table LIMIT 100) to "Users/name/Downloads" With CSV
EOF
```